# DNS resolver doesn't act as expected for local network addresses

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I'm a long-time Fedora user, but now I have an Ubuntu (18.04.04 LTS) system on my network (it's a Jetson Nano Developer Kit, in case that matters). I'm having trouble resolving addresses for hosts on the local network. I run dnsmasq on the local network to provide caching DNS and DHCP services for all machines on that network and it just works for all of my Fedora hosts. However, addresses for hosts on the local network are not resolved from the ubuntu machine but external Internet addresses are. For example, this is what "dig" produces from one of my Fedora machines on the same network:

```
[hwuser@b00 ~]$ dig hw-fs
; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1-RedHat-9.11.6-5.P1.fc30 <<>> hw-fs
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18123
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hw-fs.             IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hw-fs.          0   IN  CNAME   e04.
e04.            0   IN  A   192.168.36.192

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.36.3#53(192.168.36.3)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 26 10:06:56 EST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

Here's what is produced from the ubuntu machine:

```
hwuser@j00:~$ dig hw-fs
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> hw-fs
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 42973
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hw-fs.             IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 29 07:07:31 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 34
```

So looking at `/etc/resolv.conf` I see:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I'm not familiar with systemd-resolve, but running `systemd-resolve --status` produces:

```
hwuser@j00:~$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.36.3
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (dummy0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

I also managed to enable debugging information for systemd-resolved. This is what that log shows when I try `dig a14` from the ubuntu machine:

```
Jan 29 07:46:52 j00 systemd-resolved[13114]: Got DNS stub UDP query packet for id 51024
Jan 29 07:46:52 j00 systemd-resolved[13114]: Looking up RR for a14 IN A.
Jan 29 07:46:52 j00 systemd-resolved[13114]: Sending response packet with id 51024 on interface 1/AF_INET.
Jan 29 07:46:52 j00 systemd-resolved[13114]: Processing query...
```

Running `ip route` results in the following:

```
default via 192.168.36.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.36.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.36.66 metric 100
```

As requested, running `dpkg -l *dnsmasq* results in:

```
hwuser@j00:~$ dpkg -l *dnsmasq*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                              Version                       Architecture                  Description
+++-=================================================-=============================-=============================-=======================================================================================================
un  dnsmasq                                           <none>                        <none>                        (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base                                      2.79-1                        arm64                         Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
un  dnsmasq-base-lua                                  <none>                        <none>                        (no description available)
```

And now the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

After adding my DNS server address to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (although this should not have to be done manually, since that's the whole point of what dnsmasq provides automatically):

```
hwuser@j00:~$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.36.3
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.36.3
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (dummy0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

hwuser@j00:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Oct 22  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

hwuser@j00:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I feel like there some crucial missing piece here, something that is not configured correctly. How do I get systemd-resolve to use the DNS server on eth0?

I saw this question: [Ubuntu Clients Ignore DNS Server on local network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664670/ubuntu-clients-ignore-dns-server-on-local-network), but the answer does not fix my problem, since I don't want dnsmasq to run on my ubuntu machine (I already have it running on the network and so I don't need the duplication).

Comment: Try installing the libnss-resolve pakage.  That seemed to be missing in 18.04 (and later), but should fix your local name resolution, which is not a DNS lookup anyway.

Comment: `libnss-resolve` didn't seem to help. I still get the same results when trying to resolve hosts on the local network. I'm confused by what @ubfan1 says that this not a DNS lookup; it absolutely is, since the hosts I'm trying to find are on the local network.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` and `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Ok, I've done as @heynnema asked.

Comment: It looks like you're setup correctly. But... try this... edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and fill out the `DNS=` and `FallbackDNS=` fields, and remove the leading `#`. Reboot. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Ok I've done this, but I still get the same result (i.e. no host resolution on the local network). I'm now wondering if I should just get rid of systemd-resolve; it seems to be broken for my situation. I'm not using it on my Fedora hosts and they work.

Comment: Show me the current `systemd-resolve --status` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema Ok, I've done what you asked. Adding the DNS server manually is IMO not the right solution (even if it did work, which it doesn't) because that's the whole point of using dnsmasq, to provide everything automatically.

Comment: Did you remove the libnss-resolve package, because your posted /etc/nsswitch.conf is lacking the "resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]" words just before "dns" (which is all the package install actually does I think). Look at apt-cache show libnss-resolve, the description seems to be what you want. Local names resolution works for me, getting ips from a router, using the systemd-resolvd and the libnss-resolve

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried editing /etc/nsswitch.conf to put "resolved" on the "hosts:" line, as well as reinstalling libnss-resolve, but neither seemed to help. There must be something fundamentally different about this system that breaks name resolution, because from everything I've read (and the helpful comments here) has indicated that it should work.

Comment: @EricSokolowsky Looks like it should all work. I'm out of ideas for now. Please let me know if you find a solution... as inquiring minds need to know :-)

Comment: Just checked, and I do see an initial ping lname failure, but after a ping ip of lname, then ping lname works.  Seems to be  some buffering going on here.

Comment: I couldn't resolve machine names on my local network either, until I found out I needed to suffix their machine names with '.local', for example machine named 'fred' needs to be addressed from Ubuntu as 'fred.local'.